# Font Identification of Body Text

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone please help me identify the font in the attached image?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Proxima Nova Regular](https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova).

By the way, with such amount of text you could easily identify that with [WhatTheFont](http://www.whatthefont.com).

Comment: Thank you very much - I did try WhatTheFont and it could not do it. Also tried IdentiFont with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If this was written on a website you can always try the [WhatFont plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm) for Google Chrome.

Comment: Omg, where has this been all my life?

Comment: The plugin is a nice find. If you don't like to install additional plugins, and don't mind the extra steps, you can use the "element inspector" tool of your browser. The "computed style" section has that same info.

Comment: In English in most browsers it's called 'Inspect element' - it's one of the options when you right-click anywhere on a web page. In Chrome, 'Inspect Element' then choose 'Elements' then 'Computed style'; in recent versions of Firefox, 'Inspect Element' then the Style button then 'Computed' at the top. Also try the Firefox inspect element '3D view' button which gives you a crazy rotatable 3D visualisation of how the whole web page is structured...

Comment: This is a useful tool but probably should be a comment rather than an answer, as it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @thomasrutter I agree it's not an answer per se, but it did have two positive votes, and if it was helpful once it could be helpful again.

Comment: Never said it wasn't helpful.  Some comments are very helpful and I'm sure this comment would continue to be helpful as a comment!  But this isn't actually intended as an answer to this question, that's all.  I presume the distinction between answers and comments should be the same as on other SE sites, no?